# Should i use AWS IAM or my root credentials for my webapp access to S3 bucket?

Tags: security, permissions, user-accounts, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a webapp that requires uploading/deleting/reading files inside a S3 bucket.

What I did was I created a brand new Amazon WebServices (aka AWS) account. Let's call this AWS account `team@webapp.com`

I created a S3 bucket `webapp-cdn` when logged in as `team@webapp.com`

I know I need a key and secret so that my webapp can have read-write access to the bucket.

The `team@webapp.com` AWS account has a security credentials page which shows me this IAM system.

I created a User called `webapp_system` inside the IAM and a Group called `s3_all_access`. I put the `webapp_system` User inside the Group `s3_all_access` and granted ALL access to ALL buckets for members of this Group.

There is no way to select only specific buckets for access when I created the Group.

Now the User has its own key and secret. I can also generate a **root credentials** for the account `team@webapp.com` consisting of key and secret.

My question is which access keys should I use? I am confused by this IAM which I have never used before. At the same time, I appreciate having more granular User Authorization controls.

I have the following buckets setup in the same S3 account.

- `webapp-cdn` : this is for LIVE server
- `webapp-stage`: this is for Staging server
- `webapp-devt`: this is for testing during development

I have tried exploring Role in IAM. It appears to be unsuitable.

I am not sure what is best. Ideally I prefer to have 1 unique pair of access key for each bucket. This is to reduce chances of developers leaking keys to the bucket responsible for the LIVE server.

I have read the [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#What_is_AWS_Identity_and_Access_Management) but it confused me further than enlightened me.

Please advise.

Thank you.